# Can´t install Rstudio in Ubuntu "Dependency is not satisfiable: libssl1.0.0|libssl1.0.2|libssl1.1"

Tags: r, ubuntu, dependencies, rstudio-server, libssl

Does have someone the same issue?
i'm trying to install Rstudio, so downloaded the current version and i got the following:

It is worth mentioning that I had several previous versions of Rstudio downloaded so I renamed it as rstudio-new

```
kevin@kevin:~/Descargas$ sudo gdebi rstudio-new.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading status information... Done
Reading status information... Done
Cannot install this package
The dependency is unsuccessful: libssl1.0.0|libssl1.0.2|libssl1.1
```

I already tried sudo apt-get update and sudo apt get-install (libssl version) as well as trying to install previous versions and I have not been successful in any :( the info of my pc is:

[image]

I have tried other things as well, such as downloading several versions of libssl, but I have not been successful either:

```
sudo gdebi libssl1.0.0-dbg_1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.27_amd64.deb

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree... Done

Reading status information... Done

Reading status information... Done

Cannot install this package

Dependency is unsuccessful: libssl1.0.0 (= 1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.27)

sudo apt-get install libssl-dev

Reading package list... Done

Creating dependency tree... Done

Reading status information... Done

libssl-dev is already in its most recent version (3.0.2-0ubuntu1.7).

0 updated, 0 new to install, 0 to remove and 0 not updated.
```

Does anyone by chance know what is causing this? It should be mentioned that I already had (a long time ago) R and Rstudio but I had to uninstall them because I didn't use them, but now I do need them

Comment: You can usually get an older library version 'individually' from packages.ubuntu.com, see for example here _by pointing at 'impish' aka 21.10_:  https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libssl&searchon=names&suite=impish&section=all  -- the issue is clearly with the RStudio builds though.  For what it is worth I also run one of the dailies and update every few days.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here. I have *solved* it installing a [daily release of the next version](https://dailies.rstudio.com/rstudio/elsbeth-geranium/electron/jammy-amd64/).